# Integrating Angular Universal into existing CLI Applications

Tags: angular, universal

I followed exactly the 5 steps to integrate universal to an existing angular cli project:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

The problem is that i dont have any server.js file in dist/server...i tried to build several times.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server.js` file should be in the main `/dist` folder, not in the `/dist/server`folder. 
The npm command from the Wiki `npm run serve:ssr`starts the file `node dist/server` which actually means `node dist/server.js`

Hope that helps!